# Adding onload and onchange event listeners in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to add an `onchange` and `onload` event listeners to my JavaScript code without using libraries, but first is what I have written correct? I used and IFFY in the middle of my code to ensure variable privacy, and wonder if that makes sense in this particular case.

For now all I want to do is make Total Invoiced display "0€" or the value of the sum of Invoiced and Previous Invoiced.

Where must I insert the `onchange` event listeners for Invoiced and Previous Invoiced.

Here is the link to my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MMendes/gLsBG/

My HTML

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <table class="register">
        <caption>Register</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr class="heads">
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Route</th>
                <th>Invoiced</th>
                <th>Previous Invoices</th>
                <th>Total Invoiced</th>
                <th>Not Collected</th>
                <th>Previous Not Collected</th>
                <th>Consumption Expenditures</th>
                <th>Other Expenditures</th>
                <th>Total Route</th>
                <th>Total Collected</th>
                <th>Difference T.R&#8722;T.C</th>
                <th>Deposited</th>
                <th>In Register</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="date"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="route" class="boxed" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="invoiced" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="lastinvoiced" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
                <td id="daytotal"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="notcollected" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="notcollectedlate" class="boxed" />&euro  </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="expenditure1" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="expenditure2" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
                <td id="total"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="totalcollected" class="boxed" />&euro</td>
                <td id="difference"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" id="deposite" class="boxed" />&euro;</td>
                <td id="registered"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS

```
.boxed {
border-style: none;
overflow: auto;
width: 70%;
margin: 2%;
}
body {
margin: auto;
padding: 2%, 5%, 2%, 5%;
}
caption {
font-size: 2em;
font-family:"Courier";
}
table {
border-radius: 0.5em;
border-style: solid;
background: olivedrab;
}
td {
background: darkgreen;
opacity: 0.9;
width: contain;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

My JS

```
var A = {

//calculate the total invoiced for the day
calcTotalDay: function () {
    //get the total invoiced for the day and set the value to 0€
    var dayTotal = document.getElementById("daytotal");
    if (dayTotal === "" || dayTotal === isNaN) {
        dayTotal.innerHTML = "0€";
    } else {
        (function () {
            //get the input values for invoiced and lastInvoiced "parsed as integers"
            var invoiced = parseInt(document.getElementById("invoiced").value, 10);
            var lastInvoiced =parseInt(document.getElementById("lastinvoiced").value,  10);
            //make sure the input values are number types. If not display message demanding to insert a valid value
            var type1 = typeof invoiced;
            var type2 = typeof lastInvoiced;
            if (type1 !== "number") invoiced.innerHTML = "Insert a valid value!";
            if (type2 !== "number") lastInvoiced.innerHTML = "Insert a valid value";
            //return the sum of the total by adding invoiced and lastInvoiced and     adding the euro sign
            if (type1 === "number" && type2 === "number") {
                dayTotal = invoiced + lastInvoiced + " €";
                return dayTotal;
            } else {
                return "invalid";
            }
        }());
    }
   }
   };
```

Comment: are you asking where to apply the `onchange` event to perform the task you want? because ... that's a question only you can answer. we can help with **how** to implement, not figuring out **where** to implement.

Comment: There are several issues with your code.
1. You seem to treat `invoiced` and `lastInvoiced` at the beginning as a number or a value and later as an DOM element (`invoiced.innerHTML`).
2. You check that type1 or type2 are of the `number` type, but even if it is a `NaN` (which `parseInt("a", 10)` returns), its type is still `number`. `typeof parseInt("a", 10) === "number"`.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea my doubt about where 'onchange' would be best used is because I have the two values I want to get after the user has input them and then add them and use that value to go into Total Invoiced. But that aside, how could I implement 'onchange'?

Comment: @PhistucK I see what you mean.

Comment: Also, I believe the change event is triggered only when the field loses its focus. If you want to check the value while the user types it, use the keydown, keypress or keyup events.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the entire calcTotalDay function (after correcting its code) needs to run within the change event listener of both of the fields. So you can run your entire code within the load event and add event listeners for the relevant elements that would run the calcTotalDay function.

Also, for compact cross browser event listener addition code, there are many examples for that, just use your favorite search engine.